# My mongoose model do not have db property and no query is running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing myself a fairly complicated solution on top of Mongoose for liveQueries and such. It is all on [github here](https://github.com/capaj/Moonridge), in 22 commits in. I have a little test project there also in directory test.
I have one awful problem with my models. I have a helper method which creates my models from string param and object param for schema. This seems to work, models are created, but they lack db property. Also model.collection.conn and model.collection.collection are null.

When I compare them to my manually created models, they lack db, so they don't have connection to DB and all queries are just buffered and not executed. How is it that they lack the db property? I am connecting through mongoose.connect() so shouldn't all models have that one connection?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was caused by require('mongoose') called separately in other files. So all it took was just passing a mongoose object to where I needed it as an argument.
Why did I think that mongoose would behave like a singleton I don't know. I am glad that I know it now.